# undefined method `all_text_fields' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I am using Rails 2.1 and implemented Sunspot search. The server is running fine, but the problem is when I am searching for a text, it is showing an error like this:

```
undefined method `all_text_fields' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anybody knowledgeable about the solution to this problem please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: can you just give more details on the error, like in which class it is occurring and what is your code like. Rails provides all these details so you can copy and paste it here so that we can help you :D

Answer (score 1):

That's most likely an error coming from inside the sunspot gem. It can occur if your model isn't setup right. Do you have a searchable block in the model you are trying to run a search on?

e.g.:

```
class Foo > ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    integer :size
  end
end
```